# How to measure the convergence time of OSPF in Quagga?

Tags: routing, ospf, quagga

What command(s), softwares/tools can I used to measure the convergence time in Quagga running an OSPF network? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a common non-Quagga-specific recipe:

1. Fire a continuous ping test over the main path established by OSPF.
2. Disrupt the main path.
3. Wait until OSPF restores connectivity for ping.
4. Record how much time elapsed between steps 2 and 3.